# Как подключить svg file в view (шаблонизатор blade)?

Tags: laravel, svg

Как подключить svg file в view (шаблонизатор blade)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="{{asset('/images/svgimage.svg')}}">
```

путь относительно папки public